# show child value on parent in hierarchy query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have this 3 tables Accounts(id,name,parent), CostCenters(id,name,parent) and AccountPerCostCenter(account,costcente) the first two are hierarchical tables and the last one is the one I use to link them.

Here are the creates and some sample data to make my question more understandable

```
Create table Accounts(id number, name varchar2(100), parent_id number);
insert into Accounts
Select 1, 'ACTIVE', null from dual union all
Select 11, 'CURRENT ASSETS', 1 from dual union all
Select 111, 'CASH AND CASH EQUIVALENTS', 11 from dual union all
Select 112, 'GENERAL BOX', 11 from dual union all
Select 12, 'GENERAL BOX', 1 from dual union all
Select 121, 'PETTY CASH', 12 from dual union all
Select 122, 'CASH IN BANKS', 12 from dual union all
Select 13, 'BANKS ACCOUNTS', 1 from dual union all
Select 131, 'CENTRAL BANK OF AMERICA', 13 from dual union all
Select 132, 'BANK PROMERICA', 13 from dual union all
select 133, 'BANK DAVIVIENDA', 13 from dual union all
select 1331, 'BANK SCOTIABANK', 133 from dual union all
select 1332, 'BANK PROMERICA EXEMPT', 133 from dual;

create table CostCenters (id number, name varchar2 (100), parent_id number);
insert into CostCenters
select 1, 'Cash flow from operating activities', null from dual union all
select 2, 'Adjustments to reconcile net (loss) to net cash (used)', 1 from dual union all
select 3, 'Provided by operations', 1 from dual union all
select 4, 'Depreciation', 3 from dual union all
select 5, 'Capital Increase Capitalization Accounts Payable to Shareholders', 3 from dual union all
select 6, 'Changes in Assets and Liabilities of the effects of Operation', null from dual union all
select 7, '(Increase) in Accounts Receivable', 6 from dual union all
select 8, 'Decrease in receivables related parties', 6 from dual;


create table AccountsPerCostCenters (account number, CostCenter number);
insert into AccountsPerCostCenters
select 112,2 from dual union all
select 133,4 from dual;

alter table accounts add constraint accounts_pk primary key (id);
alter table costcenters add constraint costcenters_pk primary key (id);
alter table accountspercostcenters add constraint accountspercostcenters_pk primary key (account, costcenter);

alter table accounts add constraint accounts_fk foreign key (parent_id)references accounts (id);
alter table costcenters add constraint costcenters_fk foreign key (parent_id)references costcenters (id);
alter table accountspercostcenters add constraint apcc_accounts_fk foreign key (account)references accounts (id);
alter table accountspercostcenters add constraint apcc_costcenters_fk foreign key (costcenter)references costcenters (id);
```

As you can see not all account as link to a cost center and the link can be at any level of the tree. So what I'm trying to get is a full tree of account for each cost center, I get the account tree with

```
select id, name, level  from accounts acc
connect by prior acc.id=acc.parent_id
start with acc.parent_id is null

id      name                        level
---------------------------------------------
1       ACTIVE                      1
11      CURRENT ASSETS              2
111     CASH AND CASH EQUIVALENTS   3
112     GENERAL BOX                 3
12      GENERAL BOX                 2
121     PETTY CASH                  3
122     CASH IN BANKS               3
13      BANKS ACCOUNTS              2
131     CENTRAL BANK OF AMERICA     3
132     BANK PROMERICA              3
133     BANK DAVIVIENDA             3
1331    BANK SCOTIABANK             4
1332    BANK PROMERICA EXEMPT       4
```

and what I like to get is something like this

```
Id      Name                        Level    Cost Center
--------------------------------------------------------
1       ACTIVE                      1        112
11      CURRENT ASSETS              2        112
111     CASH AND CASH EQUIVALENTS   3        112
112     GENERAL BOX                 3        112
1       ACTIVE                      1        133
13      BANKS ACCOUNTS              2        133
133     BANK DAVIVIENDA             3        133
1331    BANK SCOTIABANK             4        133
1332    BANK PROMERICA EXEMPT       4        133
```

I know I have to do the join with the AccountsPerCostCenter to get the last column but I don't know ho to get it in all the rows and get the full accounts tree for each cost center I try this

```
Select acc.id, acc.name, level, apcc.costcenter
From accounts acc
    left join accountspercostcenters apcc on acc.id=apcc.account
connect by prior acc.id=acc.parent_id
start with acc.parent_id is null
```

but I don't get neither of the things I'm looking for.

edit..
added the keys to the tables

Sorry I had a mistake in the result im lokking for, I only need the full tree of 
the accounts that are actualy link to the cost center not all the accounts for each cost center so the cross join gives me more rows than the ones I need, again sorry for not explaining myself in the right way.

I'm using oracle 11g r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for each account you need to find his parents, grandparents, children, grandchildren and so on. This query does it:

```
with apcc as (select distinct account id from AccountsPerCostCenters),
a as (
  select id, name, decode(level, 1, 1, -level) l, connect_by_root(id) root
    from accounts 
    connect by prior parent_id = id
    start with id in (select id from apcc)
  union
  select id, name, level l, connect_by_root(id) root
    from accounts 
    connect by parent_id = prior id
    start with id in (select id from apcc) )
select id, name, 
    rank() over (partition by root order by l) lvl, root cost_center
  from a order by root, l
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba1159/1)

Please note that result does not contain row with id=111. It is not child nor parent of 112, I suspect this is mistake in output generated by hand.
There is no logical reason to show this row.

In SQL we start from certain point (account from apcc) and build two hierarchical subqueries in two ways. Next we union them. Final query sorts and enumerates levels.

Comment: thanks for the answer this is just what I was trying  to do but i didnt knew how again thx so much.

and yes the row with id 111 was a mistake when I tried to generate the example of the data I wanted

Comment: I thought about this question a bit more and I think that in penultimate line you may want to use [dense_rank](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dense_rank.php) instead of [rank](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rank.php) - please use one that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the output you described:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        select acc.id,
               acc.name,
               level AS depth
        from   accounts acc
        connect by prior acc.id=acc.parent_id
        start with acc.parent_id is null
       )
       CROSS JOIN
       AccountsPerCostCenters apcc;
```

Not sure if a `CROSS JOIN` is what you intended or if there is a better way of linking the two tables? You haven't included any foreign keys in your DDL and there is no obvious natural join.